# SQL Join with three tables

Tags: php, sql, join

Yesterday I have been testing one single query for over hours and hours, but I never succeeded. These are the three tables:

```
USERS:
#### id: 1 ##### name: Admin ##### Hometown: The Hague

POSTS:
#### id: 1 ##### userid: 1 ##### title: Test I ##### opinion: agree
#### id: 2 ##### userid: 1 ##### title: Nope.. ##### opinion: disagree

REACTIONS:
#### id: 1 ##### userid: 1 ##### opinion: agree
#### id: 2 ##### userid: 1 ##### opinion: disagree
```

And this is what I want:
I want the basic information of the user (name, hometown, etc) and I want to count how much compliments (post - opinion: agree), how much complaints (post - opinion: disagree), how much positive reactions (reaction - opinion: agree) and how much negative reactions (reaction - opinion: disagree) this person has posted.

This is the query I use now:

```
    SELECT
        u.name, u.hometown,

        SUM(IF(r.opinion="disagree",1,0)) AS agrees
        SUM(IF(r.opinion="disagree",1,0)) AS disagrees,

        SUM(IF(p.opinion="agree",1,0)) AS compliments,
        SUM(IF(p.opinion="disagree",1,0)) AS complaints

    FROM
        users AS u

    LEFT JOIN
        reactions AS r
    ON
        r.userid = u.id

    LEFT JOIN
        posts AS p
    ON
        p.userid = u.id

    WHERE
        u.id = 1
```

The problem is that this does not give me the correct information. It returns values like 8 positive reactions, though there are only two reactions in the DB.

I think it has something to do with GROUP BY p.id, r.id but I tried that and it did not work... Could someone enlighten me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS? You need use subqueries to sum the reactions by user separately to the posts by user because currently you are cross joining posts and reactions which will mean you get lots of duplication

Comment: Seem to be missing a comma after agrees.

Comment: Yeah, I was just typing this in my browser, not the actual code I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS, you might be able to do this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSTS WHERE POSTS.userid = USERS.id and opinion = 'agree') compliments,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POSTS WHERE POSTS.userid = USERS.id and opinion = 'disagree') complaints,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REACTIONS WHERE REACTIONS.userid = USERS.id and opinion = 'agree') positive_reactions,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REACTIONS WHERE REACTIONS.userid = USERS.id and opinion = 'disagree') negative_reactions
FROM USERS
```

Comment: This does work, but 4 correlated sub-queries would *usually* be better refactored to a join on uncorrelated sub-queries.

Comment: @Dems Not on a DBMS with decent optimizer. Correlated subqueries do not necessarily mean NESTED LOOP and, interestingly enough, the NESTED LOOP is not always the slowest way. Making this kind of blanket statement without actually **measuring** is not justified.

Comment: This indeed worked for me. Dems solution gave me an error, I'll try to get that fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be the grouping, your joins are joining multiple records form one table, to a single record in another.  This is causing your duplication.

For example, for a single entry in the user table, you may have 3 responses in reactions, and 3 responses in posts.  Your query is returning 9 records, because all of that user's reactions are joined to all of that user's posts...

```
userid | reaction_id | post_id
  1           1           1
  1           1           2
  1           1           3
  1           2           1
  1           2           2
  1           2           3
  1           3           1
  1           3           2
  1           3           3
```

This means that you need to aggregate the reactions separately from the posts...

```
SELECT
    u.name, u.hometown,

    r.agrees
    r.disagrees,

    p.compliments,
    p.complaints

FROM
    users AS u
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    userid,
    SUM(IF(r.opinion="agree",1,0)) AS agrees
    SUM(IF(r.opinion="disagree",1,0)) AS disagrees,
  FROM
    reactions
  GROUP BY
    userrid
)
  AS r
    ON r.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    userid,
    SUM(IF(p.opinion="agree",1,0)) AS compliments,
    SUM(IF(p.opinion="disagree",1,0)) AS complaints
  FROM
    posts
  GROUP BY
    userid
)
  AS p
    ON p.userid = u.id
WHERE
    u.id = 1
```

Comment: There were some syntax errors, but after I fixed those it still does not give me the result I wanted: numbers are off. Branko's solution does work, so I think I'll go with that one. Thanks for your help though :)!

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
select id, name, hometown, sum(agrees) agrees, sum(disagrees) disagrees,
  sum(compliments) compliments, sum(complaints) complaints
from (
  select u.id, u.name, u.hometown,
    if(p.opinion = 'agree', 1, 0) agrees,
    if(p.opinion = 'disagree', 1, 0) disagrees,
    0 compliments, 0 complaints
  from users u
  left join posts p on u.id = p.userid
  union all
  select u.id, u.name, u.hometown,
    0, 0,
    if(r.opinion = 'agree', 1, 0),
    if(r.opinion = 'disagree', 1, 0)
  from users u
  left join reactions r on u.id = r.userid
) as S
group by id, name, hometown
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.name, users.hometown, myPosts.compliments, myPosts.complaints,        myReaction.agrees, myReaction.disagrees
from Users users
LEFT JOIN
(
    select post.userid as userid
         , SUM(CASE WHEN post.opinion = 'agree' THEN 1 END) as compliments
         , SUM(CASE WHEN post.opinion = 'disagree' THEN 1 END) as complaints
    from Posts post
    group by post.userid
) as myPosts
on users.id = myPosts.userid
LEFT JOIN
(
    select reaction.userid as userid
     , SUM(CASE WHEN reaction.opinion = 'agree' THEN 1 END) as agrees
     , SUM(CASE WHEN reaction.opinion = 'disagree' THEN 1 END) as disagrees
    from Reaction reaction
    group by reaction.userid
) as myReaction
on users.id = myReaction.userid
```